# Passing data from another form to another form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a problem regarding passing data from a form to another form.
This is for my assignment in school.
In my 1st form I have a button and 3 textboxes which are labeled id, name and address. When I click the button another form will appear and I also want the first form to be not accessible. The 2nd form shows list of data (id,names, addresses) which are from database which I have already created. After selecting the desired data there is a button labeled 'select' with the following code:

```
private void metroButtonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedwcNo = metroGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string selectedwcFullname = metroGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string selectedwcAddress = metroGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

}
```

---

and I dont know what to do next. I want to pass these data to my first form

Comment: what is metrogrid?Gridview?

Comment: yes it is a gridview

Comment: so you can use templateview to handle click events and Eval parameters to pass parameters to any method which will be using in your program using grid view.

Comment: See my two form solution on following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class for your values:

```
public class Person
{
    public string No {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;} 
}
```

In your second form add `readonly` public property, from where you get selected data.

```
public class SecondForm
{

    private Person _SelectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _SelectedPerson; }
    }

    //Set data to the SelectedPerson in your click eventhandler
    private void metroButtonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _SelectedPerson = new Person();
        _SelectedPerson.No = metroGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        _SelectedPerson.Name = metroGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        _SelectedPerson.Address = metroGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

Then in your first method create method which open Second form and return selected data

```
public class FirstForm
{

    private Person GetSelectedPerson();
    {
        Person selected = null;
        using(var secondForm = new SecondForm())
        {
            secondForm.ShowDialog();
            selected = secondForm.SelectedPerson;
        }
        return selected;
    }

    //And use above method in button click eventhandler
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person selected = this.GetSelectedPerson();
        if(selected != null)
        {
            //Show selected data in the textboxes
            this.TextBoxNo.Text = selected.No;
            this.TextBoxName.Text = selected.Name;
            this.TextBoxAddress.Text = selected.Address;
        }
    }
}
```

`secondForm.ShowDialog()` method will show form as modal, which will make first form not accessible.

Comment: sorry , where I will put the class for my values is it in my first form or second form?

Comment: Put it in own file for example. That class need to be accessed from both forms

Comment: sorry i still dont get it where will i put these:

Comment: public class Person
{
    public string No {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;} 
}

Comment: how i will  display the selected no, name and address in my textboxes?

Comment: private Person GetSelectedPerson();
    {
        Person selected = null;
        using(var secondForm = new SecondForm())
        {
            secondForm.ShowDialog();
            selected = secondForm.SelectedPerson;
        }
        return selected;
    }

Comment: i dont know why i cant run the program; this line return errors

Comment: Error 89 Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.mwSearchwscust.Person' to 'WindowsFormsApplication1.mwCashier.Person' C:\Users\maarahoy\Documents\latest form\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\mwCashier.cs 64 24 JOEFFATS WINDOWS FORM

Comment: Seems like you create two different `Person` classes. Right click on your project name in the Solution explorer of Visual Studio - > Add -> Class -> Give a name "Person". Delete all previously created "Person" classes in `mwSearchwscust` and `mwCashier.Person`. Then use their your newly created `Person` class

Comment: thank you sir Fabio. It help my group in school alot. God Bless

Answer (score 0):

To make new form:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.show();
```

To hide form:

```
this.Hide();
```

I dont really know what you want exactly do but maybe this will help 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI3ad-TebP0